# Unable to distinguish between two fragments with chart click events

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener, anychart

[image: Respected community, Please see the attached screenshot in which you'll be able to see the problem that I am dealing with.]I have implemented two pie charts in two different fragments. Whenever I click on a pie chart it will call the second fragments click events on both fragments.

### Here is my MainActivity.java code.

```
package longitude.com.anychart;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.ValueDataEntry;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */


    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private AccountDashboardAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        //mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        ArrayList<DataEntry> dateData = new ArrayList<>();
        dateData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Apples", 123456));
        dateData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Pears", 852465));
        dateData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Bananas", 753159));
        dateData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Grapes", 963215));
        dateData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Oranges", 415263));


        ArrayList<DataEntry> collectorData = new ArrayList<>();
        collectorData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Applessssss", 6371664));
        collectorData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Pearsssss", 789622));
        collectorData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Bananasssss", 7216301));
        collectorData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Grapesssss", 1486621));
        collectorData.add(new ValueDataEntry("Orangesssss", 1200000));

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<DataEntry>> childData=new LinkedHashMap<>();

        childData.put("Apples",collectorData);
        childData.put("Pears",collectorData);
        childData.put("Bananas",collectorData);
        childData.put("Grapes",collectorData);
        childData.put("Oranges",collectorData);

        childData.put("Applessssss",dateData);
        childData.put("Pearsssss",dateData);
        childData.put("Bananasssss",dateData);
        childData.put("Grapesssss",dateData);
        childData.put("Orangesssss",dateData);


        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new AccountDashboardAdapter(getResources(), getSupportFragmentManager(), dateData, collectorData, childData);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class AccountDashboardAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private final List<DataEntry> collectorData;
        private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<DataEntry>> childData;
        SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
        List<DataEntry> dateData;

        /**
         * Create pager adapter
         *
         * @param resources
         * @param fm
         * @param data
         * @param childData
         */
        public AccountDashboardAdapter(final Resources resources, FragmentManager fm, List<DataEntry> data, List<DataEntry> collectorData, HashMap<String, ArrayList<DataEntry>> childData) {
            super(fm);
            this.dateData = data;
            this.collectorData = collectorData;
            this.childData = childData;
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            final Fragment result;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    // First Fragment of First Tab
                    //result = new DatewiseAccountDashboardFragment();
                    result = new fragment1();

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("data", (Serializable) dateData);
                    bundle.putSerializable("childData", childData);
                    result.setArguments(bundle);


                    break;
                case 1:
                    // First Fragment of Second Tab
                    //result = new CollectorwiseAccountDashboardFragment();
                    result = new fragment2();

                    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                    bundle1.putSerializable("data", (Serializable) collectorData);
                    bundle1.putSerializable("childData", childData);
                    result.setArguments(bundle1);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    // First Fragment of Second Tab
                    //result = new CollectorwiseAccountDashboardFragment();
                    result = new fragment1();

                    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                    bundle2.putSerializable("data", (Serializable) dateData);
                    bundle2.putSerializable("childData", childData);
                    result.setArguments(bundle2);
                    break;
                default:
                    result = null;
                    break;
            }


            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "DATEWISE";
                case 1:
                    return "COLLECTORWISE";
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * On each Fragment instantiation we are saving the reference of that Fragment in a Map
         * It will help us to retrieve the Fragment by position
         *
         * @param container
         * @param position
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        /**
         * Remove the saved reference from our Map on the Fragment destroy
         *
         * @param container
         * @param position
         * @param object
         */
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            registeredFragments.remove(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }


        /**
         * Get the Fragment by position
         *
         * @param position tab position of the fragment
         * @return
         */
        public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

### My First Fragment1.java code

```
package longitude.com.anychart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anychart.APIlib;
import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.chart.common.listener.Event;
import com.anychart.chart.common.listener.ListenersInterface;
import com.anychart.charts.Pie;
import com.anychart.enums.Align;
import com.anychart.enums.LegendLayout;

import java.util.List;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    private AnyChartView anyChartView;
    private List<DataEntry> data;
    private Pie pie;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);

        data = (List<DataEntry>) getArguments().getSerializable("data");
        //childData = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<DataEntry>>) getArguments().getSerializable("childData");
        getArguments().remove("data");
        getArguments().remove("childData");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        anyChartView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view1);
        anyChartView.setProgressBar(rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar1));
        showChart(anyChartView, data);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void showChart(AnyChartView anyChartView, List<DataEntry> data) {

        APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(anyChartView);
        pie = AnyChart.pie();

        pie.data(data);
        pie.title("1st Anychart Title");
        //pie.labels().position("outside");

        pie.innerRadius(50);

        pie.legend().title().enabled(true);
        pie.legend().title(false);

        pie.legend()
                .position("center-bottom")
                .itemsLayout(LegendLayout.HORIZONTAL_EXPANDABLE)
                .align(Align.CENTER);

        //pie.fill("aquastyle");

        pie.labels().format("{%x}\\n{%value}");


        anyChartView.setChart(pie);

        pie.tooltip(false);

        pie.setOnClickListener(new ListenersInterface.OnClickListener(new String[]{"x", "value"}) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Event event) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fragment1==>" + event.getData().get("x") + ":" + event.getData().get("value"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

### My Second Fragment2.java code

```
package longitude.com.anychart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anychart.APIlib;
import com.anychart.AnyChart;
import com.anychart.AnyChartView;
import com.anychart.chart.common.dataentry.DataEntry;
import com.anychart.chart.common.listener.Event;
import com.anychart.chart.common.listener.ListenersInterface;
import com.anychart.charts.Pie;
import com.anychart.enums.Align;
import com.anychart.enums.LegendLayout;

import java.util.List;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    private AnyChartView anyChartView;
    private List<DataEntry> data;
    private Pie pie;

    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);

        data = (List<DataEntry>) getArguments().getSerializable("data");
        //childData = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<DataEntry>>) getArguments().getSerializable("childData");
        getArguments().remove("data");
        getArguments().remove("childData");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        anyChartView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view1);
        anyChartView.setProgressBar(rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar1));
        showChart(anyChartView, data);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void showChart(AnyChartView anyChartView, List<DataEntry> data) {

        APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(anyChartView);
        pie = AnyChart.pie();

        pie.data(data);

            pie.title("2nd Anychart Title");

        //pie.labels().position("outside");

        pie.innerRadius(50);

        pie.legend().title().enabled(true);
        pie.legend().title(false);

        pie.legend()
                .position("center-bottom")
                .itemsLayout(LegendLayout.HORIZONTAL_EXPANDABLE)
                .align(Align.CENTER);

        //pie.fill("aquastyle");

        pie.labels().format("{%x}\\n{%value}");


        anyChartView.setChart(pie);

        pie.tooltip(false);

        pie.setOnClickListener(new ListenersInterface.OnClickListener(new String[]{"x", "value"}) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Event event) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fragment2==>"+event.getData().get("x") + ":" + event.getData().get("value"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

### fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="BACK" />

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YnIL1fE52W_Gy4yuc2rYb4fh4Y1hGNuG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please post the relevant code here as it not a good way to ask for people to download your code and look into it.

Comment: Ok I have posted my code as well as posted a screenshot of my problem, please have a look now and if possible recommend me a resolution.

Comment: did you find solution even I am facing same issue

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, now we have no idea what exactly happens with event dispatching in Fragments. But I would like to bring to your attention that there's a possible workaround.
Click on a chart returns correct point name and value. Only the fragment name is wrong. The name is hardcoded in the click event handler. 
So if the fragment name is not required in output, you can just drop it. If the name is required you can apply a specific ID to the Fragment and then get that ID from active fragment view. This should solve the issue as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Please fix the issue mentioned in Question even I am facing same with multiple fragments showing charts